# How to get same Random number in jmeter regex extractor

Tags: jmeter

[image]I have one request where i have added 3 regex extractor which will extract value1, value2 and value3.

In first Regex i have added Match no as 0 so i will always get random match from all the matching pattern.

Now my requirement is, due to random behavior if match no 5 selected in fist regex then same match no should be passed in other two regex so i can extract associate value.

So whatever match no get's automatically selected in first regex, same match number should be used in next two regex. Please let me know how i can achieve this.

Comment: can you explain the scenario  with an example?

Comment: Can you please edit you question with the response from server and what exactly you want. still unclear.

Comment: I have Get request where i have added 3 regex extractor which returns multiple occurrence of value 1, 2 and 3.In all the 3 regex i have mentioned Match No as 0 so all the regex will return random match no from the matching pattern. But my requirement is, if i get match no as say 3 in first regex the other two regex should also return 3 matching pattern. I always want to use same match no which was selected in first regex.

Comment: ok you can have -1 as match number so that get all the matches. Then you can select a fixed random match from all the regex.

Comment: Please checkout the image. Now you can see my first regex....my other reg ex are exactly same...only change is expression for second regex "value2":(.*?) and third regex  "value3":(.*?),. If i use 0 as match no then first regex is returning match as 3, second regex returning match no 5 and third is returning match no 7....My requirement is...if first regex return match no 3 then other two regex should return match no 3...next iteration first regex return match no 8 then other two regex should select matching pno as 8 only...i hope my question is clear

Comment: Yes now it is clear i would say you use -1 to get all the matches and then decide on which match to pick. There is no way you can control the random selection of regex extractor. For the behaviour that you are expecting you need to get all the matches for all three regex and then decide on the index randomly.

Comment: thanks Vikas for the help...i will use -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use -1 to get all the matches.

Use a bean shell to generate a random number (with range 0 to max match)

Then use

```
${value1)_${randomvar}, ${value2)_${randomvar}, ${value3)_${randomvar}
```

to get a fixed random match accross regex.